# CNN forming same output for all inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm trying to teach a CNN to classify images from the following data set: [kaggle.com/nih-chest-xrays/data](http://kaggle.com/nih-chest-xrays/data)

I decided to start with the [GoogLeNet model](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.4842.pdf) however I have replaced the fully connected layer with a 14 dimensional output using the sigmoid function (classes are not mutually exclusive). I'm having some problems getting the model to learn, it seems to be the case that in trying to minimize the loss it's learning the mean of my data as after a short while it will output the same output `e.g. [0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]` for all the input images.

I've searched around a bit, including the currently featured questions, but can't seem to find a solution elsewhere as my dataset is reasonably big (112k images) and I've tried the typical suggestions I see in other questions.

I've tried:

- Changing optimizer from Adam to Adagrad
- Changing unweighted cross entropy loss to weighted loss as described [here in 3.1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.02315.pdf)
- A much smaller 2 layer network (NaiveCNN.py linked)
- Altering the learning rate in the region 0.1-0.00001
- Verifying my input pipeline is actually sending different images to the CNN, not just an entire batch of the same image.
- Using an explicit weight initializer instead of the tensorflow default one. (Used the tflearn default one `tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.001)`)
- Using tensorflow's inbuilt `tf.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` rather than an explicitly defined cross entropy.
- Both my predictions and labels are shape [64,14] and `tf.transpose`ing throws an error as expected `Incompatible shapes: [64,14] vs. [14,64]` so I don't think it's that either

I'm using a batch size of 64 on a GTX1080ti, using tensorflow 1.4.0, [typical TensorBoard output from 30 epochs of training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyLyD.png)

All the code I'm using is [here: https://gist.github.com/Kaapp/abdb54b232eb7f07b87955d9a18df57d](https://gist.github.com/Kaapp/abdb54b232eb7f07b87955d9a18df57d)

I'm starting to think it's probably just a simple error somewhere in my code but I've been looking at it for so long I can't spot it or I've just misunderstood something. Apologies for the confusing bits of code, I added a few _x,_y etc variables just to help when debugging what exactly the network is outputting.

[Small dataset (1000 images) example from my comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TqPL.jpg)

Edit/Update: I've found that removing the dropout layer in my model makes this totally consistent, model outputs begin at 0.5 across the board and will move together each batch while predicting the same output for the entire batch.

Comment: Can you overfit a tiny dataset?

Comment: If I set num_examples=1000 in my dataset methods and train on that, this is what I am seeing. [link](https://imgur.com/a/nC08j6U)

As you can see in TensorBoard my loss actually gets worse from inital 0.5 predictions then plateaus. The learning rate is not being dropped because validation set accuracy improves by very small amounts (0.001 ish) each epoch, but outputs do not seem to change.

After 7 epochs, always outputting:
[ 1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.]

After 8 epochs, always outputting:
[ 1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.]

Comment: I will keep training it to see if the validation/training accuracy will ever diverge but I don't think so as it seems to be stuck here.

Comment: And the same for naive?

Comment: Updated the imgur album with naive, it displayed the same behavior until I [updated the loss and initializers to match GoogLeNet](https://gist.github.com/Kaapp/abdb54b232eb7f07b87955d9a18df57d/revisions) However, it is also dropping the learning rate every epoch as validation is getting worse. So it seems that the updated naive will overfit on a small set but the small variation in output numbers on different images makes me think that perhaps it is too small to extract much meaningful info from the data?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to train the entire network, rather than just take the pre-trained GoogLeNet and re-structure/re-train the last layer or two. Is this correct? You may just not have enough data to train that whole huge monster; maybe try loading existing network weights and then freezing all but the last couple of layers for your data?

Comment: Yep, this was what I was trying to do - I can try swapping the model for the one found in the TF-slim library which comes with pretrained weights but I will have to upgrade TF version first as the [code for that checkpoint](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/inception_v1.py) is not working for me on 1.4. I'll give it a try though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using a pretrained model solved my issue. I couldn't initially load the pretrained model due to a subtlety with the way the tensorflow saver works.

To fix this I needed to re-intialize the Saver once my graph's construction was actually complete so that it was aware of entire graph and then manually initialize the extra variables, then finally restore the checkpoint like so:

```
vars_to_init = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, "the_added_layer's_scope")
for var in vars_to_init:
    sess.run(var.initializer)
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.restore(sess, my_checkpoint_file_path)
```

Once I had done this I could fine-tune an existing model checkpoint by training only the final layer by passing the variables to the minimize function:

```
trainable_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, "my_trainable_variables_scope")
self.train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(
                        learning_rate=self.lr, 
                        beta1=0.9,
                        beta2=0.999).minimize(self.loss,var_list=trainable_vars)
```

It seems that perhaps my data set is not varied enough to train a network properly from scratch, but fine tuning the final layer works very well.

Hopefully this might help someone else if you get stuck in the same way I did.